# How do i get a list of branches from a github repository?

Tags: python, github

I want a list of all my branches from a repository from github. so i can do something like this.

```
print(branches[1])
```

and ill get an output of a branch name. I haven't found a straight answer on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g = Github("key")
repo = g.get_repo("link to repo")
versions = []
for branch in repo.get_branches():
    versions.append(branch.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_output(['git', 'branch']).decode().split('\n')
```

---

Another possibility:

```
from pygit2 import Repository

repo = Repository(path_to_your_repo) # use '.' if you are already there
repo.branches
```